# c++20 modules (experimenting with Xcode 11)

Tags: c++, xcode, module

I'm having trouble getting c++20 modules to work with Xcode (v11 beta5).

I'm trying this:

```
// file a.cppm (also tried naming it a.cpp or a.cc)
export module a;
int x;

// file b.cpp
import a;  // ERROR: Module 'a' not found.
int y;
y = x;
```

- I get the ERROR : "Build Time" -> "Parse Issue": Module 'a' not found.
- there are no other warning/errors (and, therefore, it would seem that modules *are* supported by compiler/linker).
- I note that the build created no precompiled module a.pcm.

My Xcode project build settings are: using clang gnu++2a language dialect + libc++. compiling with -fmodules-ts and -std=c++2a. also enabled "Enable Modules (C and Objective-C) [no option available for C++].

so, my questions:

1. does Xcode (10 or 11) clang support c++20 modules? (I wish to avoid using headers)
2. if so, what additional configurations do i have to do?

Do i perhaps have to specify explicitly/manually (as compiler arguments) any intermediate output (eg. precompiled .pmc files/paths)? that would however be contrary to the purpose of an IDE, but perhaps Xcode only provides partial support?

Comment: Since clang doesn't support modules yet, I presume that Apple's build of clang also does not support modules yet.  https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html

Comment: @Eljay. thx. at least as of april 14 2019 it should with the -std=c++2a enabled. https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/commit/cab7f1f7bc141ac88d15030088b311bd450b2c94. but if that is included/available in xcode 11, im not sure. surely the switch -std=c++2a is accepted within xcode, clang.

Comment: If you need the most current available stable release of LLVM, you can use [brew](https://brew.sh/) and then `brew install llvm`.

Comment: @Eljay. thx, i followed your advice, along with setting the path and rebooting. unfortunately, the "module not found" error remains.

Comment: I don't have any more suggestions.  Both modules and contracts are the two upcoming features that I am highly anticipating and excited about.  I hadn't thought either has made it to the mainlines yet of any mainstream compiler.  I think both features are very hard, and will take time before they land in any compiler's mainline.